# jquery autoResize textarea does not work when in jquery ui tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

jquery autoResize textarea does NOT work when in jquery ui tab.

jquery autoResize works outside of tab.

See both examples in jsFiddle.  Click the "Details" tab to see it not resize.

http://jsfiddle.net/remy/6BwqE/25/

this is using the autoresize by James Padolsey http://james.padolsey.com

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug appears to be when the original element is not visible on the page and thus the `clone` function in the plugin fails to find the width. This can be resolved by the following steps:

1. Change `clone` to be a function (remove wrapping parens and `()`)
2. Call the clone function in `updateSize`
3. Trigger the `updateSize` event whenever a tab is shown or loads (up to you)

I've made the modifications in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/6BwqE/29/

I inlined the modified source for the autoResize plugin and added a `show` event to the `tabs` call.